# Cannot set default value to simple hierarchical views exposed filter field

Tags: 8, views

I have a views block displayed on a page. It has simple hierarchical select exposed filter field to which i want to set default value when the page loads. I have written below code in `hook_form_alter` but it does not work.

`$form_state->setUserInput(['tid' => '47']);`

When i check in preview section of views my taxonomy is selected and works perfectly but on page it does not work.

Thank's in advance